# Balancing max threads based on tasks priorities

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose we have 10 threads and I have three different kind of tasks that are independent of one another. At beginning we know, Task 1 needs 6 threads, Task 2 needs 3 threads and Task 3 needs 1 thread.

Task priorities go like this : Task 1 > task 2 > Task 3 .

Now if suppose there is no task 3 and only we have task 1 and task 2, then the  threads should get distributed in equal ratio (if thread count left idle is even or else one more thread to higher priority task)
Similarly, if we have all Task 1 done, then Task 2 and Task 3 need to distribute threads.

How this can be achieve in Java multithreading. Is there some kind of such balancer available already ?

Comment: I would think that you should create a thread pool (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) with 10 threads and then assign tasks to the threads based on your needs.  You will need to write the balancing logic, but that is quite simple.  If this is not suitable, then I will need more context about your problem and how this falls short.